# Cannot display toast in a catch

Tags: android

```
package com.example.m2mai;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class RetrieveActivity extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_retrieve);
    }



    public void getStream(View v)
    {   
        new MyAsyncTask().execute();
    }

private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{   
    ArrayList<String> mNameList = new ArrayList<String>();
    public ArrayList<String> atList=new ArrayList<String>();
    public ArrayList<String> dataList=new ArrayList<String>();


        protected String doInBackground(String... params) 
        {
            return getData();

        }
        public long getDateTo() 
      {
        EditText toText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.dateTo);
        String To = toText.getText().toString();

        DateFormat dateFormatTo = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Date dateTo = null;
        try {
            dateTo = dateFormatTo.parse(To);
        } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
            .runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                  public void run() {
                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please key in the correct input",    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  }
                });
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        long timeTo = dateTo.getTime();
        new Timestamp(timeTo);  
        return timeTo/1000;

      }

        protected String getData()
        {
            String toTS = ""+getDateTo();
            String decodedString="";
            String returnMsg="";
            String request = "http://api.carriots.com/devices/defaultDevice@eric3231559.eric3231559/streams/?order=-1&max=10&at_to="+toTS;
            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;  
            try {
                url = new URL(request); 
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                connection.addRequestProperty("carriots.apikey", "1234567");
                connection.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                connection.setRequestMethod("GET"); 

                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                while ((decodedString = in.readLine()) != null) 
                {
                    returnMsg+=decodedString;
                }
                in.close();
                connection.disconnect();
                JSONObject nodeRoot = new JSONObject(returnMsg); 
                JSONArray res = nodeRoot.getJSONArray("result");

                 for (int i = 0; i < res.length(); i++) 
                    {
                    JSONObject childJSON = res.getJSONObject(i);
                    if (childJSON.get("data")!=null)
                        {
                       String value = childJSON.getString("data");
                       dataList.add(value);
                       JSONObject node=new JSONObject(value);
                       atList.add(node.get("temperature").toString()); 
                        }
                    } 
                 }
                 catch (Exception e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace(); 
                returnMsg=""+e;

            }
            return returnMsg;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
            {


            for(int i = 0; i < atList.size(); i++)
            {
            ListView mainListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);


            ArrayAdapter<String>  mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(RetrieveActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,mNameList);


            mainListView.setAdapter(mArrayAdapter);

            mNameList.add(atList.get(i).toString());
            mArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            EditText myData1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            myData1.setText(atList.get(0));

            }
    }

}
```

How can I actually display a toast without stoping it? Whenever it falls into the catch it is not responding.

............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: you can't toast inside a catch, instead that use some variables to return and toast that variable outside the try catch block.

Comment: What are you wanting? A dialog box? Toasts do not permanently display.

Comment: I just wanna to display a toast that tell the user to enter correct input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following:

1. In `getDateTo()`:

   ```
   try {
       dateTo = dateFormatTo.parse(To);
   } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
       runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
             public void run() {
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please key in the correct input",    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }
           });
       e.printStackTrace();
       return -1L; // attention here

   }
   ```
2. In `getData()`:

   ```
      long dateTo = -1L;
       if((dateTo = getDateTo()) == -1L){
           return null;
       }
       String toTS = "" + getDateTo();
   ```
3. In `onPostExecute`:

   ```
   if(result == null) {
           return;
       }
   ```

Comment: getData or getDate ? i don't have getDate() in my program

Comment: You are totally my savior ~ =D ~ tq so much. but may i know . how about  throws exception how does it works

Comment: the whole thing that keep unfortunately stop is because i didn't set  if(result == null) {
        return;
    } in the onPostExecute ?

Comment: Maybe at the end of `getData` some exception occur: 
    
    `catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                returnMsg = "" + e;

            }
            return returnMsg;`

So at `onPostExecute`, the result is not null, but that is not you want.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using `try-catch` in a `worker thread` and want to display `Toast`, then I am afraid it is not going to work. You will have to do it in `Main(UI) thread`.

Try following:

```
try {
    dateTo = dateFormatTo.parse(To);
} 
catch (java.text.ParseException e) {

your_activity_context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
  public void run() {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please key in the correct input",    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
});

e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: hi there your_activity_context <-- what should i put here

Comment: you must be using this try-catch in a thread or asynctask, which might be in fragment or Activity. So in any case you can get the Activity context to call that method. Refer [this](http://android.okhelp.cz/java_android_code.php?s=runOnUiThread)

Comment: it is an activity . i have no idea what should i put it showing error

Comment: private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> < is this the activity ?

Comment: Post the relevent code...as an Update in your question.

Comment: Ok. As [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)) method id provided by Activity class itself, you can call it directly when used in your activity (your case), however you can still call it on activity context as RetrieveActivity.this.runOnUiThread. I hope it helps you now. If it does then mark it as answer.

Comment: Ritesh, the toast did come out but it still unfortunately stopped. May i get some help on that ?

Comment: it work on the toast but still the apps unfortunately stopped

Answer (score 0):

Make `boolean flag = false;` **globally**.

Inside **catch block** make `flag = true;`

Run Toast inside an `if` block like

```
if (flag) {
Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry, Couldn't find anything!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

inside your `onclick` method.